# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking some help with configurating Laravel. Managed to create new project but accessing http://localhost/website/public/index.html gives me following error (ps. http://localhost/website/public/index.php works fine):

```
1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 142:
in RouteCollection.php line 142
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 744
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 229
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 118
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 86
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: What would you expect? You're not serving a static `index.html` page are you?

Comment: I am new to this and I don't quite know how to route this request. How can I setup my own 404 error page?

Comment: Okey, I figured it out. In resources -> views -> errors I could create my own 404 error page. In app -> exceptions -> handler.php I had to return this page.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not by default server .html files.

You should setup apache or nginx to send traffic to index.php if no local file exists.

You then need to define routes in your routes file. You could choose to create a route called `index.html` but usually you would just have a `/` route.